# Angular js json access value name

Tags: angularjs, json, html-table

I am trying to make auto generating table from json with angularJS , but how do i access name of value its self , for example  this is json i get

```
    {"data":{"selectView":[{"employeeCode":"1","employeeFirstName":"name","employeeLastName":"lastName"},
{"employeeCode":"2","employeeFirstName":"name1","employeeLastName":"lastName1"}]}}
```

I have sent that trough main.js to my controller , in which i have done this
 $scope.employee = employee.data.selectView;

And i am using ng-repeat="employee in employee"

It is object json , what am i doing wrong ?

How can i return value "employeeCode" or "employeeFirstName" , i have tryed (key,value) in employee on ng-repeat , but it returns whole row (`{"employeeCode":"1","employeeFirstName":"name","employeeLastName":"lastName"}`)

Any ideas ?

EDIT UPDATE

Solution was `<th ng-repeat="(key, val) in employee[0]">{{key}}</th>`

Comment: If one of the answers below matches what you did accept the answer, otherwise post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @Malkus Forgot about it , sorry :) thanks for reminding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was `<th ng-repeat="(key, val) in employee[0]">{{key}}</th>`

for td's i used

```
     <tr ng-repeat="dataItem in data" ng-click="newLocation(data[$index])">

       <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in dataItem">{{val}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple Html table and apply ng-repeat on the

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
      <td>{{employee.employeeCode}}</td>
      <td>{{employee.employeeFirstName}}</td>
      <td>{{employee.employeeLastName}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

in the app.js assign the json array to $scope.employees

Answer (score 0):

**In Your Controller/Module File (.Js File)**

```
$scope.data = [
{
employeeCode":"1","employeeFirstName":"name","employeeLastName":"lastName"
},
{
"employeeCode":"2","employeeFirstName":"name1","employeeLastName":"lastName1"
}];
```

**In Your HTML File**

```
<ul ng-repeat = "values in data">
<li>{{values.employeeCode}}</li>
<li>{{values.employeeFirstName}}</li>
<li>{{values.employeeLastName}}</li>
</ul>
```

Cheers :)

Comment: I know the basics :P thing is i want it to create its self depending on json  , so it will create <th> automaticly and <td>'s , so i need to access "employeeCode" to put it to head of table

Answer (score 0):

Since the `JSON` you are getting is an array and not an object, so you should not use (key, value).
You should use ng-repeat directly on your array.
In your `controller`, assign it to a variable like this:

```
$scope.myjson = {"data":{"selectView": [{"employeeCode":"1","employeeFirstName":"name","employeeLastName":"lastName"},
{"employeeCode":"2","employeeFirstName":"name1","employeeLastName":"lastName1"}]   }}
```

then in your html,

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="emp in myjson.data.selectView">
    <td>{{emp.employeeCode}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.employeeDirstName}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.employeeLastName}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How can i return value "employeeCode" or "employeeFirstName" , not value of employeeCode , but value that would say : "employeeCode"  , do you understand me now  ? :)